# Invoking a method which uses CompletableFuture's thenAccept()

Tags: java, spring-boot, completable-future

I have a rest API function which returns an object of type DeferredResult.

```
import org.springframework.web.context.request.async.DeferredResult;

public DeferredResult<Object> apiMethod{
CompletableFuture<Object> future = someMethod();
final DeferredResult<Object> response = new DeferredResult<>(); 

future.thenAccept(){
    //logic to populate response
}

return response;
}
```

I am writing a function which will invoke apiMethod() and use its response. I always end up getting a null response because response is populated in future.thenAccept (). Is there a way to handle this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the method continues the execution while `thenAccept` runs async. After you call `thenAccept`, the method just returns `response` afterwards, independent of if it's already populated.

Imagine the following simple code:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AtomicReference<String> result = new AtomicReference<>(null);
        CompletableFuture<String> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100_000_000; i++) {}
            return "Hello World!";
        });
        future.thenAccept(s -> {
            result.compareAndSet(null, s);
        });
        System.out.println(result.get());
    }
```

You may expect that `"Hello World!"` is printed, which is not the case; it prints out `null`. Here's the same problem: the main-thread prints the value, which will be updated async somewhen. You can fix this by joining the future:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AtomicReference<String> result = new AtomicReference<>(null);
        CompletableFuture<String> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100_000_000; i++) {}
            return "Hello World!";
        });
        CompletableFuture<Void> end = future.thenAccept(s -> {
            result.compareAndSet(null, s);
        });
        end.join();
        System.out.println(result.get());
    }
```

Now when we join the async future chain, or rather the one future that sets the value, we will see the main-thread printing out `"Hello World!"` because it will wait for the future to finish.

Now you just have to apply this fix in your code.

Comment: It works but can I handle it without making change in the apiMethod() ?

Comment: @AnujaBarve I don't think so. Keep in mind that futures are there to be ran async. When you need a result, you need to sync the "asking thread" and the "future thread". In your example, you need the result from `thenAccept` to return in. Thus, the sync has to take place in-between the call of `thenAccept` and the `return` statement. Unfortunately, this is inside `apiMethod` and you inherently can't change that.